# Django ModelForm cannot instantiate request.FILES

Tags: jquery, django, postgresql, upload, modelform

I am trying to save a file to a modelform and I can see the file in request.FILES if I just print it out on the console with "print request.FILES" which gives me;

```
<MultiValueDict: {u'ondisk': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: myfile.docx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)>]}>
```

When I go ahead and try to instantiate the form with

```
form = UnifiedFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

I get a form error saying this:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>ondisk<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Its basically complaining that "ondisk" is not there, but it clearly is. Either I am really missing something here, or something is horribly wrong.

View Code:

```
def AddFile(request): 
    """ 
    View Name: AddFile 
    URL: /files/add/ 
    Template: None 
    Parameters: fs, tags, files 
    """ 
    print request.POST 
    print request.FILES 
    if request.POST and request.FILES: 
        form = UnifiedFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        print form print form.errors 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            print 'form was valid' 
            print form.cleaned_data  
            f = form.save(commit=False)
```

Comment: Did you specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form ?

Comment: Could you post the view code?

Comment: Yes, its on the form and I am also using jQuery Fileupload (which works fine).

Comment: If I set required=False in forms.py I can get past the is_valid() check, but my "ondisk" is just set to None. The problem is that UnifiedFileForm() doesnt seem to like getting request.FILES as an argument. Can't read it somehow.. request.POST reads just fine.

Comment: Another update. Even when using the python debugger (PDB) I get no errors. My Models just seems to not enjoy recieving request.FILES and treats it as None even though it is NOT empty.

Comment: And yes, it happens even if I dont use jQuery File Upload plugin.